# Error while parsing json

Tags: android, json

here is the structure of json which is coming valid on jsonlint. I just need to fetch the first block all details like hostid and all. I tried to parse the data but getting one error.

```
{
    "\u0000yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_attributes": {
        "hostid": 234,
        "user_id": 77,
        "hometype": "house",
        "roomtype": "Entire Home",
        "accommodates": "2",
        "city": "Chandigarh",
        "street_address": "",
        "state": "Chandigarh 160017",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "India",
        "latitude": "30.740212629732113",
        "longitude": "76.78718557730713",
        "address": "Bank Square, 17C, Sector 17, Chandigarh, Chandigarh 160017, India",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "beds": "2",
        "bathrooms": "1",
        "from_date": "2015-07-16",
        "to_date": "2015-08-19",
        "available": "",
        "amount_pernight": 100,
        "currency": "INR",
        "title": "AmazingSeaFacingPrivateRoom",
        "summery": "Title should highlight the key features and will attract guests to choose your listing! Add an innovative title that best describes your home.\r\n\r\nExamples:\r\n\r\n Amazing Sea Facing Private Room!\r\n Fully Furnished Villa!\r\n Free Welcome Drink on Arrival!\r\n",
        "mostcomman_facilities": "New Soap & Shampoo Sachet-:-Dry-cleaned Towel-:-Blanket-:-TV-:-Cable TV-:--:--:--:--:--:-",
        "extra_facilities": "Extra Mattress-:-Extra Blanket-:-Washer-:-Alarm clock-:-Laundry Service-:-Gym-:--:--:--:--:-",
        "features_facilities": "Smoking Allowed-:-Family & Children Friendly-:-Pets allowed-:-Wheelchair Available",
        "safety_facilities": "Fire Extinguisher-:-Smoke Detector-:-Carbon Monoxide Detector-:-",
        "num_bed": "0",
        "bed_type": 2,
        "currency_symbol": "",
        "servicefee": "",
        "cleaningfee": "",
        "person": "all",
        "landmark_location": "",
        "landmark_distance": "",
        "hostuniqueweb": "",
        "hosttype": "web",
        "extraperson": "Free",
        "breakfast": "Free",
        "Lunch": "Free",
        "Dinner": "Free",
        "Tea": "Free",
        "Coffee": "Free",
        "Airport": "Free"
    },
    "\u0000yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_oldAttributes": {
        "hostid": 234,
        "user_id": 77,
        "hometype": "house",
        "roomtype": "Entire Home",
        "accommodates": "2",
        "city": "Chandigarh",
        "street_address": "",
        "state": "Chandigarh 160017",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "India",
        "latitude": "30.740212629732113",
        "longitude": "76.78718557730713",
        "address": "Bank Square, 17C, Sector 17, Chandigarh, Chandigarh 160017, India",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "beds": "2",
        "bathrooms": "1",
        "from_date": "2015-07-16",
        "to_date": "2015-08-19",
        "available": "",
        "amount_pernight": 100,
        "currency": "INR",
        "title": "AmazingSeaFacingPrivateRoom",
        "summery": "Title should highlight the key features and will attract guests to choose your listing! Add an innovative title that best describes your home.\r\n\r\nExamples:\r\n\r\n Amazing Sea Facing Private Room!\r\n Fully Furnished Villa!\r\n Free Welcome Drink on Arrival!\r\n",
        "mostcomman_facilities": "New Soap & Shampoo Sachet-:-Dry-cleaned Towel-:-Blanket-:-TV-:-Cable TV-:--:--:--:--:--:-",
        "extra_facilities": "Extra Mattress-:-Extra Blanket-:-Washer-:-Alarm clock-:-Laundry Service-:-Gym-:--:--:--:--:-",
        "features_facilities": "Smoking Allowed-:-Family & Children Friendly-:-Pets allowed-:-Wheelchair Available",
        "safety_facilities": "Fire Extinguisher-:-Smoke Detector-:-Carbon Monoxide Detector-:-",
        "num_bed": "0",
        "bed_type": 2,
        "currency_symbol": "",
        "servicefee": "",
        "cleaningfee": "",
        "person": "all",
        "landmark_location": "",
        "landmark_distance": "",
        "hostuniqueweb": "",
        "hosttype": "web",
        "extraperson": "Free",
        "breakfast": "Free",
        "Lunch": "Free",
        "Dinner": "Free",
        "Tea": "Free",
        "Coffee": "Free",
        "Airport": "Free"
    },
    "\u0000yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_related": [],
    "\u0000yii\\base\\Model\u0000_errors": null,
    "\u0000yii\\base\\Model\u0000_validators": null,
    "\u0000yii\\base\\Model\u0000_scenario": "default",
    "\u0000yii\\base\\Component\u0000_events": [],
    "\u0000yii\\base\\Component\u0000_behaviors": []
}
```

And here is my code for parsing this structure :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                System.out.println("hello");
                JSONObject ob=obj.getJSONObject("\u0000yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_attributes");
                System.out.println("hello123");

                        home_type=ob.getString("home_type");
                        Log.v("home type is", home_type);
```

I am getting the following error in logcat. Here is the logcat details. plz help :

```
07-13 16:21:07.868: W/System.err(4678): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-13 16:21:07.868: W/System.err(4678):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at com.app.hostguestapp.Preview_form$Preview_form_data.doInBackground(Preview_form.java:91)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at com.app.hostguestapp.Preview_form$Preview_form_data.doInBackground(Preview_form.java:1)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-13 16:21:07.869: W/System.err(4678):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-13 16:21:07.870: W/System.err(4678):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-13 16:21:07.870: W/System.err(4678):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-13 16:21:07.870: W/System.err(4678):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: home_type=ob.getString("home_type"); theres no home_type parameter, only hometype.

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace this `JSONObject ob=obj.getJSONObject` to

`obj.getJSONArray .. because("\u000....")` is an array as the image describes

for more helpful tutorial check [this](http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95)

[image] image [source](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

and as rui santos  you should fix it to this `ob.getString("hometype");`

Comment: but \u000.... has { i.e object symbol after it so how can it be array? according to image u posted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your json response. First two elements are jsonObjects but 3rd element "\u0000yii\db\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_related" is jsonArray. Similarly "\u0000yii\base\Component\u0000_events" and "\u0000yii\base\Component\u0000_behaviors" are also jsonArray.

Comment: then how to parse this

Comment: First have your reponse jsonObject to have all elements as either jsonObject or jsonArray.

Comment: but then how json is coming as valid? If json is valid then dont u think it can be parsed by any means?

Comment: Yes valid json will be parsed. The problem is that your json is not valid.

Comment: Its valid. But what you trying to do is fetching jsonObject for every element in your json but in actual, some elements are jsonObject and some are jsonAraay. Thats why its crashing.

Comment: I don't think thats a problem since he is not trying to access it. He is only trying to access one jsonObject and that is actually a jsonObject, or is he?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONObjet subJsnObj = obj.getJSONObject("\u0000yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord\u0000_attributes");
String hostId = subJsnObj.getString("hostid");
System.out.println("JSONObject is "+ subJsnObj);

}catch(Exception e){
//exception
}
```